# Apache FOP: spaces between Arabic glyphs

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have very simple xsl-fo with Arabic text:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page" page-height="21cm" page-width="29.7cm" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2.5cm" margin-right="2.5cm">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
      <fo:region-before extent="3cm"/>
      <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page" writing-mode="rl-tb">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block font-size="48pt" font-family="Traditional Arabic" >البرمجة</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

PDF renders OK:

[image]

I need to use PDF accessibility feature (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.5/accessibility.html) and add `xml:lang="ar"` attribute to `fo:root` tag:

```xml
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xml:lang="ar">
```

After each glyph renders as standalone, i.e. with spaces between each other:

[image]

What I do wrong?

Font configuration section from FOP config:

```xml
<font embed-url="file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/trado.ttf" kerning="yes">
    <font-triplet name="Traditional Arabic" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
</font>
```

Apache FOP version - 2.5.

Comment: It’s not clear what fo:* result you want. Could you share source xml and also the fo:*-result that you expect

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I don't have any problem with fo. I have issue with rendered PDF in FOP as soon set `xml:lang="ar"`.

Comment: Ok sorry, misunderstood. In PDF/UA-1 or PDF/A-1A all fonts will be included in the pdf. Could it be that your "file:/C:/Windows/FONTS/trado.ttf" is different from the font that the pdf is using if it is not using accessibility? Btw: I don't understand Arabic, and thus the two pictures are a mystery to me.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed C:/Windows/FONTS/trado.ttf embedded into PDF in both cases. On the second picture, if we 'compress' 4 characters together (if count from right-to-left) , then they will look similar to right part on first picture.